# php jquery selected

Tags: php, jquery

I having long list of select options predefined.

So i tried something like this when i try to edit the content

```
<body>
<select id="test" ....
<option value='99'>99</option>
</select>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("select#test option[value='<?php echo $row['test']; ?>'").attr("selected", "selected");
});
</script>
</body>
```

php value is 99
Why this isn't working? Anything i did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are lacking a **]**

```
[value='<?php echo $row['test']; ?>'
```

Comment: Oh my god, guess i need to take break.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing ']' in your selector.
Change it to:

```
$("select#test option[value='<?php echo $row['test']; ?>']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

**Aliter**

Another way to select a value for select element is to use the val
i.e

```
$("select#test").val('<?php echo $row['test']; ?>');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is usually how I do it:

```
<select id="test">
    ...
    <option value="99">99</option>
    ...
</select>
<script>$("#test.val("<?php echo $row['test']; ?>");</script>
```

Basically, setting the `value` of the `<select>` element chooses the right option for you.